# How to use jq to query a value of a numeric sub-key

Tags: syntax, key, jq

I would like to use **jq** to display the value of 801.170.101 in the following JSON string:

```
{"801":{"170":{"100":"abc","101":33,"102":55}}}
```

I read that I need to use [] for numeric key names. The following works to return the 170 key and it's sub-values:

```
echo '{"801":{"170":{"100":"abc","101":33,"102":55}}}' | jq '.["801"]'
```

However, the following doesn't work:

```
echo '{"801":{"170":{"100":"abc","101":33,"102":55}}}' | jq '.["801"].["170"].["101"]'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.["801"].["170"].["101"]         
jq: 1 compile error
```

What is the correct syntax to retrieve the value of 801.170.101 (33)?

Thanks.

Comment: `jq '.["801"]["170"]["101"]'` would also work.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the keys in quotes `".."`,

```sh
jq '."801"."170"."101"'
```

or use `argjson` to make the path configurable to select on

```sh
jq --argjson path '["801", "170", "101"]' 'getpath($path)'
```